# random.choice shows the same answer if you use a variable

Tags: python, random

When I run this code, `print(x)` will print the same letter every time, and yet when I run it like the second example `print(random.choice(b))` it works as expected. What is the difference? I checked for an answer a found references to "seeding", but I am not using `random.seed()` prior to this.

```
import random
b = "Hello World"
x = random.choice(b)
print(x)
print(x)
print(x)
# same answer as many times as you want to print
print(random.choice(b))
print(random.choice(b))
print(random.choice(b))
# random choice each time
```

Comment: what is the point of printing `x` 3 times??

Comment: In Python, `x` gets a value *assigned* to it. It does not keep a 'live' connection with the line where it got that value from.

Comment: Just to show that you get the same answer for the first three and different answers for the second three, it could be any number for each one.

Comment: "Give me a random object and label it `x`. Show me the object you labelled `x`. Show it to me again. Show it to me again."

Comment: Rad, why does it get the same value assigned using the variable and not the same using the module?

Comment: There is no difference. See the last part of my answer below.

Comment: Got it, thanks user2357112. It doesn't run through the module again when asked to print x, it just prints the last x?

Answer (score 0):

`random.choice(b)` gets called only once when you assign the return value to `x`, it does not get called again each time you reference that variable. Each time you print `x` you are seeing the result of that initial assignment. When you do `print(random.choice(b))` it is calling `random.choice()`  on `b` each time. It would indeed be quite problematic if the value assigned to a variable changed each time you reference the variable.

There is really not much difference between what you are doing here:

```
x = random.choice(b)
print(x)
```

and what you are doing here:

```
print(random.choice(b))
```

The difference is that you do the latter 3 times (i.e., you call `random.choice()` 3x and print the result 3x), so you see 3 different results. If you do:

```
x = random.choice(b)
print(x)
x = random.choice(b)
print(x)
x = random.choice(b)
print(x)
```

You will see a different result each time (or at least a random result each time - it could be the same).

Answer (score 0):

By printing an assigned value 3 times will not change the value of the variable unless u call the random function to generate a new random variable again:)

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that the first one, `x = random.choice(b)` sets `x` to a random and then prints `x`, the letter that was randomly selected from `b`. It only randomly selects what `x` is when you declare `x`. The second, `print(random.choice(b))` generates a new random every time.

You could use the following code to make x equal to random.choice:

```
b = "Hello world!" 
x = random.choice
print(x(b))
```

And that does the same thing as `print(random.choice(b))`.